# How to assign a different layout to sub-case or related case

Tags: case, related-list

I have a parent case and then related cases. I want to assign a different layout to related cases than the parent case. Is there a way to do that? Can't find any option.

Answer (score 1):

Layouts are controlled by the Record Type. If your child cases are of a different Record Type, they can have their own page layout assigned.

If you are using Lightning Experience, you do have one additional option. When you build a Lightning Record Page, you may conditionally render specific components based upon field values of the viewed object. While this does not allow you to change page layouts (the Record Detail component), it does allow you to surface different supporting information or component-based functionality based on record values, even if the Cases have the same Record Type.